# Cant get elmah to send email with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah

"The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address."

I get the above and then it looks for source. The email address is fine and I have the module in place. Errors are being logged fine. WHat else can be going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you followed the setup for MVC here http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/MVC

Do you have another email address you can try?

Comment: since theres no other answer... ..got it working though but not sure what i did...